# Get bigdecimal value with scale

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have a string which has value `7`. I need to convert this value in big decimal equivalent `7.000000`. I tried `BigDecimal(String val)` and `BigDecimal(BigInteger val, MathContext mc)` constructors of **BigDecimal** but that did not work they all return `7`. How can I get `7.000000`?

Comment: What for? Have you tried string concatenation?

Comment: @JamesMcDowell You mean concatenating it with `.000000`?

Comment: Value in string may be `7.56`. It should return `7.560000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DecimalFormat` to format the output. There is no way to store the unnecessary precision in the `BigDecimal` object though.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal seven = new BigDecimal(7);
    BigDecimal sevenWithDecimals = new BigDecimal("7.12");
    DecimalFormat decF = new DecimalFormat("#.000000");
    
    System.out.println(decF.format(seven.doubleValue()));
    System.out.println(decF.format(sevenWithDecimals.doubleValue()));
}
```

output

> 7.000000
>
> 7.120000

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about how to convert it to a `String`.

The constructor of `BigDecimal` will produce a `BigDecimal` representing the value you gave it, and there's no difference between a `BigDecimal` representing the number 7 and a `BigDecimal` representing the number 7.00000, any more than there's a difference between the number 7 and the number 7.00000.

When you print it out, it needs to be converted to a `String`, and it sounds as though at that point you want to be able to specify the number of decimal places. To do that, you want to use the `DecimalFormat` class:

```
new DecimalFormat("#0.000000").format(bigdec);
```

Comment: I need to convert string in big decimal with scale of 6.